# Iterating a map to create another map

Tags: scala, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to get latest committed offset .For that I need to create a map of (partition -> offset) Example : {"0"->200,"1"->100} from Consumer.Committed(set[partitions])
consumer.committed gives output in util.map[TopicPartition,OffsetandMetaData]

Need help in create a map from util.map[TopicPartition,OffsetandMetaData]

```
  var map = Map[String, Long]() //Empty Map to populate

    val last=consumer.committed(partitions.toSet)


    last.foreach(x=>
      (map += (x._1 -> x._2.offset()))
      //println(x._1 +"->" +x._2.offset())
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `map` on the `Map` to generate a new `Map`:

```
val map = last.map { case (t, o) => t -> o.offset }
```